# Delete data from table with no roll back option

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a database with 200 million rows. I run a delete query for deleting 20 million rows.

It takes about 8 hours to delete. In the mean time after running 6 hours transaction fails due to some reason.

Now it takes 5-6 hours to roll back.

How to delete data so that if transaction fails due to some reason, it can not be roll backed?

Comment: What is a crore?

Comment: @jarlh 10 Million...

Comment: So then a part of the transaction is done, and another part is not yet done. But you are ok with that? Seems like something you need to reconsider.

Comment: There is no such way. The whole point of a transactional database is to give you transactions. To give the database less to log for each transaction, use `TRUNCATE` to delete everything at once (it does  not log individual rows and so is considerably faster) or break up your `DELETE`s in smaller batches that take less time to roll back. If you find yourself doing this often, consider partitioning your tables -- emptying individual partitions is as fast as truncating a whole table.

Comment: Do the delete in smaller batches.

Comment: There are 200 million records in which I have to delete only 20 million. So, I can't run truncate table.

Comment: delete them by one million each time. Changes are it will succeed more often, and if it does not succeeds you dont have them all rollbacked again

Comment: Finally I have deleted in smaller batches. But I want to know if there any mechanism to delete at all...

Comment: If your table is partioned then you can switch the old partition and then truncate the target. --> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191160(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I think it will depend on what errors you are experiencing.